# Ler matriz char, de um arquivo binário

Tags: c, arquivo, matriz, struct, char

Função que escreve e lê o arquivo binário:

```
int FUNCAO_QUE_GRAVA_BIN (char filename[],int partida1,char resultado1)
{
        typedef struct  {
                int partida;
                char jogvelha[3][3];
                char resultado;
        } velha;

        velha partida = {partida1,{"a","b"},resultado1},read_data;

        FILE * file= fopen(filename, "wb");
        if (file != NULL) {
                fwrite(&partida, sizeof(velha), 1, file);
                fclose(file);

                FILE* fin = fopen(filename, "rb");
                fread(&read_data, sizeof(velha), 1, file);
                printf("%d %c %c\n", read_data.partida, read_data.jogvelha[3][3], read_data.
                       resultado);
                fclose(fin);
                fflush(stdin);
                while(getchar()!='\n'); // option TWO to clean stdin
                getchar(); // wait for ENTER
                return 0;//failure //ignore
        }

        return 1; //sucesso /ignore
}
```

chamando no main :

```
        int ganhador=1;
        char local[]={"binar"};
        int partidas= 1;

  FUNCAO_QUE_GRAVA_BIN(local,partidas,ganhador);
```

o problema é que o output está saindo tudo errado, o jogvelha[3][3] não sai direito, como arrumar?

Comment: Se `jogvelha` é um array de 3 por 3, então `read_data.jogvelha[3][3]` está errado. Um array de tamanho 3 tem as casas 0, 1 e 2

Comment: @Isac no printf você diz?

Comment: Sim no `printf`

Comment: @isac    
 `printf("%d %c %c\n", read_data.partida, read_data.jogvelha[0][1], read_data.
                       resultado);`
output:
` 1,  letra do ASCII `   além de não ler certo, falta o output do `read_data.resultado`

Answer (score 2):

A escrita e leitura em arquivo que tem está correta, o problema são alguns erros e equívocos seus no código:

- Como disse em comentário o `printf` está errado pois imprime uma casa que não existe:

  ```
  printf("%d %c %c\n", read_data.partida, read_data.jogvelha[3][3], read_data.resultado);
  //                                                         ^--^
  ```

  Se tem um tabuleiro de 3 por 3, então tem as casas 0, 1 e 2. A casa 3 já está fora. É importante lembrar que a primeira casa de um array é sempre 0.
- Definiu o `resultado` como `char` na estrutura:

  ```
  typedef struct  {
      ...
      char resultado;
  } velha;
  ```

  Mas depois guarda o valor númerico 1 nesse campo:

  ```
  int ganhador=1;
  FUNCAO_QUE_GRAVA_BIN(local,partidas,ganhador);
  //                                     ^-- aqui passa um int com 1 em vez de um char
  ```

  Isso irá fazer com que veja o tal caratere estranho da tabela ASCII, mais em concreto o caratere ASCII 1.
- A inicialização do `jogvelha` também está errada:

  ```
  velha partida = {partida1, {"a","b"},resultado1}
  //                         ^^^^^^^^
  ```

  Se tem um array de chars 3 por 3 então ficaram carateres a faltar, assim como ficou uma string a faltar. Outro pormenor que se esqueceu é que se guardar os valores como strings então o compilador inclui o terminador, o que faz com que tenha espaço a menos, e precisava de ter um tabuleiro 4 por 4.

  Melhor é iniciar como `char` mesmo, escrevendo os carateres que quer manualmente:

  ```
  velha partida = {partida1, {{'X','O','X'}, {'X','O','X'}, {'X','O','X'}}, resultado1};
  ```